# How to rename artifact on rest api build promotion

Tags: rest, build, rename, artifactory, promotion-code

I am relatively new to artifactory trying to achieve the below pointers.

1.) After QA approval trying to promote Jars from snapshot to release artifact(actual promotion works) but promoting to release artifact is not changing version name.

whether it is possible to change/rename artifact on rest api build promotion.?

2.) Also please suggest how we can achieve roll-back scenarios here.

Any inputs are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The build promotion REST API does support changing the version name.
[enter link description here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BuildPromotion)
You can change the version name using a custom [promotion user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Promotions). You can see some [examples](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/build) of build promotion plugins in the JFrog Dev Github account.
Specifically, the [promotion.groovy](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/build/promotion) plugin contains example of [copying](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/build/promotion/promotion.groovy#L132) staging artifacts to release artifacts.
A good place to start is the [user plugins](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) wiki page and the Artifactory [public API](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/index.html) documentation.

The [Artifactory Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) supports more advanced [release management](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management) capabilities, including the option to rollback.

Comment: Thanks Very much for your response. 1.) since i don't have any Idea of how Groovy works. Can you point out how we can achieve this using curl rest api..? 2.) I have already heard about release management Jenkins plugin. we are following a Single project gradle  structure for now & we are producing non-unique artifact version. 3.)whether it is possible to implement release management plugin for single project gradle structure with non-unique version..

Comment: Can you please share me some example in groovy.? how to change version name using custom promotion user plugin. It will be great. @drorb